# Wordpress Uploads Path Issue

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

Long time since I've asked a question here but I've come across an unusual issue that I'm unsure how to rectify so hoping someone has a suggestion!

I've just moved a wordpress site to a new host out of development.
The website content is in a folder path like this: /www.websitename.ca/web/content/

However image files are accessed directly with a URL like this www.websitename.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/image.jpg

Thought everything was working great. Site looks like it should after the move and all images are linked correctly being in the path /www.websitename.ca/web/content/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/

I've added a new plugin and it is working.

When I attempt to upload images though I am unable to and get the message "Unable to create directory uploads/2015/11. Is its parent directory writable by the server"

My first attempt was to change File Permissions to 777 but that didn't work.

I then attempted to define the uploads path in wp-config.php with

```
define('UPLOADS', '/web/content/wp-content/uploads');
```

But that wrecked all the image urls and it wasn't uploading properly.

So basically I'm looking for a way to define the upload path that doesn't affect the viewing path?

Should I do this in htaccess?

Contacted the host to better understand how their redirects work, but thought I would reach out incase anyone has any experience with a similar issue.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay answer turned out to be pretty simple and I was on the right path with defining the Upload path.

This worked:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads');
```